# Apps Script, Using jquery DataTables With Additional Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, datatables, include

I am attempting to write a script that pulls data from a google sheet and posts to an html table.  If I strictly do the code.gs with the required doGet function, and only add html/javascript via a scriplet  (i.e., ) for the table ONLY, it works fine.  However, if I try to add any additional functions it stops working. However, I wanted to add some additional functions.  I was trying to add a function that adds the current month and day at the top of the page.  I've tested this code for the month/day completely separate from the the table, and it too works fine.  But when I try to add it to the Javascript file in combination with the code for the table, I get this error:

**
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' (line 2, file "Code")**

I thought perhaps it was a problem with which code was loading first, and that the it was calling for the necessary files before they loaded.  I attempted "document.ready" and window.onload, but neither fixed.

I think the problem is with the scriplet and when it tries to include the Javascript.  I've tried moving the scriplet in the code as well, but that hasn't solved the problem.

Here is the code.  I appreciate any help in advance.

```
**code.gs**
   function doGet(){
   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
  }
 
   function getData(){
      
      var spreadSheetId = "1-CkmSe_dDNZJNWTTz6EfqOiFjSkP7ZdiLT3XeyBSH60"; 
      var dataRange = "Data!A2:C";
      var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId,dataRange);
      var values = range.values;
      return values;
   }

   function include(filename) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
   }

**Index.html**
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"    
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   
     href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  
    <?!= include('StyleSheet'); ?>

     </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
   
    <div class="datetime">
      <div class="date">
        Entry For:  
        <span id="dayname">Day</span>,
        <span id="month">Month</span>
        <span id="daynum">00</span>,
        <span id="year">Year</span>
      </div>
          </div>
    <div class="container">
      
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
        </table>

      </div>
    </div>  

  </body>
    <?! = include('JavaScript'); ?>
  </html>
  
**JavaScript.html**
<script>
    
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
 
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
  
          columns: [
          {"title":"Date "},
          {"title":"Year"},
          {"title":"Event"},
      ]
      });
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){
  function updateClock(){
      var now = new Date();
      var dname = now.getDay(),
          mo = now.getMonth(),
          dnum = now.getDate(),
          yr = now.getFullYear(),
          hou = now.getHours(),
          min = now.getMinutes(),
          sec = now.getSeconds(),
          pe = "AM";

          if(hou >= 12){
            pe = "PM";
          }
          if(hou == 0){
            hou = 12;
          }
          if(hou > 12){
            hou = hou - 12;
          }

          Number.prototype.pad = function(digits){
            for(var n = this.toString(); n.length < digits; n = 0 + n);
            return n;
          }

          var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",     
          "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
          
          var week = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", 
          "Saturday"];
          
           var ids = ["dayname", "month", "daynum", "year", "hour", "minutes", "seconds", 
           "period"];
          
           var values = [week[dname], months[mo], dnum.pad(2), yr, hou.pad(2), min.pad(2),  
           sec.pad(2), pe];
          
           for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++)
           document.getElementById(ids[i]).firstChild.nodeValue = values[i];
    }
  
    $(document).ready(function(){
       function initClock(){
       updateClock();
       window.setInterval("updateClock()", 1);
      }
     });
  });
`
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=' (line 2, file "Code")`? Because, when I tested your script using `values` with a sample value, no error occurs. I apologize for this. First, I would like to correctly replicate your current issue.